# Postgres: - Fetching particular format date values from a Text Column having varied data

Tags: postgresql, date, format

I have a table with one text column which can have varied data(Text, varchar fields etc) My requirement is to fetch the data from this column for date values having particular format.

Eg: - Table Column Data(Table x_test with column C2): - 'abc','01-Nov-2019','1/15/2019','xyz'

Query I am trying to use : - 
select to_date(c2, 'DD-MON-YYYY') c2
from x_test

It is returning error currently

Comment: `'abc','01-Nov-2019','1/15/2019','xyz'` is all in a single column?

Comment: Could you please provide an exact sample of data? (and I hope that the assesment of 404 is not true... There is normal forms to respect in RDBMS structure architecture...)